# JPA/EclipseLink: Understanding ClassLoader issues

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, classloader, apache-commons-dbcp

**EDIT: Although a (good) answer was given and awarded, this only covers a rather unimportant part of my question. The main parts of this question are still open.**

I use EclipseLink (2.6.2) in a cloud project. The project is a web application packaged as a `WAR` file and deployed on Apache Tomcat 8. The persistence context is set up using Java code, where I specify the entities to use using `entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(packagesToScan)`. This configuration normally works as expected, where exactly the entity classes in the specified packages are found.

I now fail to understand when to use which classloader, especially when considering Tomcat, running tests, and using different connection pool implementations.

When running on Apache Tomcat including Tomcat's connection pool, the `DataSource` instance is created using the `spring-cloud-connector` plugin (`spring-cloud-spring-service-connector`).
In this setting everything works as expected, as long as I don't change the classloader as described below (otherwise I face `ClassNotFoundException`s for the entity classes).

When running unit tests with the help of `JUnit` and `spring-test`, the `DataSource` instance is created using the in-memory database H2 (using `EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder` from `spring-jdbc`). In this setting I have to specify JPA to use the classloader used for the `DataSource` instance (key `eclipselink.classloader` in the JPA properties map), otherwise I get "Object ... is not a known Entity type".

When running tests in an embedded Apache Tomcat 8, I don't see any message indicating the connection pool in use. In this setting I also have to set the classloader as for the unit tests.

If I add `commons-dbcp` (2.1.1) to my project and explicitly configure the `spring-cloud-connector` plugin to use it instead of Tomcat's connection pool, I can run the application on Tomcat without configuring the classloader, but it also works with the classloader specification described above.

For the tests the `commons-dbcp` does not change anything compared to the scenarios outlined above (as the corresponding configuration is not used).

Summary:

- Tomcat (Tomcat CP): only using the unmodified classloader for JPA
- Tomcat (DBCP): both variants
- Tests: only using `DataSource`'s classloader for JPA

Could you help me understand the differences here, and suggest a simple solution suitable for all cases? I assume that DBCP and Spring use a different classloader than Tomcat (and Tomcat's connection pool).

If you need further information, I will happily add it.

EDIT: I added an example project with a big README on how to reproduce.

https://github.com/C-Otto/classloaderexample

Comment: Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35318985/spring-cloud-connector-1-2-1-classnotfoundexception-for-entities

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your questions mix of DataSource, Connection Pool, and Service Discovery (spring-cloud-service-*).



I think it is best for you to create case study using simple project in github and ask your exact problems here.

Comment: @xsalefter I added an example project with some documentation. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Just found why yor tomcat:run not work with your CloudDatabaseConfig. You need to configure postgresql dependency on the tomcat7-maven-plugin. I will try find the other erros now.

Comment: @fhofmann actually it works, just not in all variants of the configuration. What do you mean with "configure postgresql dependency"?

Comment: I could not reproduce the tests erros. I am getting a diferent one: "com.test.BaseEntity is not a known Entity type". Hope that my "answer" helped.

Comment: The error you mentioned is exactly what I see. Can you explain it? Why do I need to set a different classloader?

Answer (score 5):

"I get another error when I start using mvn tomcat7:run, use Tomcat's
 connection pool (CloudDatabaseConfig) and do not re-configure the
 classloder (JpaConfig):"

You must configure the PostreSQL dependency on the maven plugin. You are getting ClassNot found because the PostgreSQL JAR is not in the path:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <port>8080</port>
    <path>/</path>
  </configuration>
  <!-- For any extra dependencies needed when running embedded Tomcat (not WAR dependencies) add them below -->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.4-1206-jdbc41</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Also have a look at https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/run-mojo-features.html

I forgot to include the class loader change on (JpaConfigWithDatasourceClassloader.getJPAProperties):

```
properties.put(CLASSLOADER, new java.net.URLClassLoader(
   ((java.net.URLClassLoader)classLoader).getURLs(), JpaConfigWithDatasourceClassloader.class.getClassLoader()  ) 
) ;
```

With this you can run all variants using `tomcat7:run`

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about plugin dependencies. I added some information to your answer, this really helped. For the classloader issue: To me it seems your snippet just shows a different way of configuring the class loader to be used by JPA. I still do not understand why this configuration is necessary at all, and why it is causing problems depending on the connection pool and the start/test setup.

Comment: I am not an expert in Tomcat classloader, but looking to the code i imagine that the Datasource is loaded with the container classloader and your Entities with application classloader. If you pass container classloder to JPA it wont see the claases you have in your war.

Comment: The DataSource object is constructed inside my application, so this can't be the case. But it is very likely that the connection pool implementation was created with another classloader, and that this is causing problems.